# Why throughput value changes in every run in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

My throughput value changes in every run for the same test. What might be the reason behind this?
Example:- I have created 10 samples for a http request & after running it I get a throughput value of 10.6/sec. If i run it again the throughput changes to 11.2/sec. Then again if i run the throughput value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Throughput depends on response time for fixed set of users(threads). If you server is able to respond in constant response time then throughput will remain the same for a given number of clients(threads).

Comment: "Throughput depends on response time." --- this is not entirely true. Response time can be high and the throughput can be also high in the same time.

Comment: I meant to say that if the server responds in constant response time then we can see constant throughput. For fixed set of users throughput depends on response time (littles law)

Comment: here the user is seeing differnt throughput because his server is responding at different response time. lets say he has 10 cilents running in parallel if the server responds in 1 seconds then he will see 10 req/sec. If server responds at 2 seconds then it will be 5 req/sec. So for a fixed number of clients to see fixed throughput the server should respond in constant response time.